# Que signifie « céan(s) » dans Le Tartuffe (Molière)

Tags: sens, histoire, littérature

Je ne peux pas trouver une définition en ligne, mais mon amie l'avait cherché dans Larousse de Poche:

> **céan** - *Maître de céans*, maître des lieux

Et un peu de contexte de *Le Tartuffe* (Acte I, Scène I):

> **Damis**
>
> Quoi ? je souffrirai, moi, qu'un cagot de critique
>
> Vienne usurper **céans** un pouvoir tyrannique,
>
> Et que nous ne puissions à rien nous divertir,
>
> Si ce beau monsieur-là n'y daigne consentir ?

Donc il me semble que *céans* fait référence à ceux qui avait le pouvoir - les propriétaires fonciers, les nobles, etc., mais je ne suis pas sûr...

Que veut-dire *céans* dans ce contexte ?

---

I can't find a definition online, but my friend looked it up in Larousse de Poche:

> **céan** - *Maître de céans*, maître des lieux

And a bit of context from *Le Tartuffe* (Act I, Scene I):

> **Damis**
>
> Quoi ? je souffrirai, moi, qu'un cagot de critique
>
> Vienne usurper **céans** un pouvoir tyrannique,
>
> Et que nous ne puissions à rien nous divertir,
>
> Si ce beau monsieur-là n'y daigne consentir ?

So it seems to me that *céans* is referencing those who had power - property owners, nobles, etc., but I'm not sure...

What does *céans* mean in this context?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Céans](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/c%C3%A9ans) ne se rencontre plus guère qu'en littérature. Cet adverbe signifie étymologiquement « ici, dedans » et c'est bien le sens qu'il à toujours dans l'oeuvre de Molière : « ici, en ce lieu ».

Il est invariable, donc la graphie sans s est erronée.

Comment: Cela ne peut-il pas aussi signifier "immédiatement" ?

Comment: @LaurentS. Rarement, et le tlfi indique qu'il semble s'agir d'un faux archaïsme.

Comment: "Un traître de Sarrasin se cache ici céans, et je le découvrirai, Abdallah de Bourgogne!" (Didier Bourdon) : Un faux archaïsme en effet, fruit de l'humour des Inconnus